# Перенаправление с одной деректории в другую

Tags: php, javascript

Люди нужна помощь.
Короче есть сайт где есть файлы и мне надо сделать так, чтоб к этим файлам не было прямого доступа.

```
например:
http://site.ru/userfile/file.doc
```

Но мне надо сделать запрос с get параметром

```
htp://site.ru/?view=post&path=file.doc
```

и в обработчике делаю так

```
$path = "userfile/".$_GET['path'];
```

---

Я пробовал закрыть доступ через .htaccess вот так. Т.е перенаправляю

```
RewriteRule ^userfile/(.*)$ htp://site.ru/ [L,R=301]
```

Но в этом случае get запрос с обработчика не работает. 
Что посоветуете?
Есть ли какой-то вариант перенаправить?

Answer (score 1):

1. Закрываем файл от посторонних в .htaccess

```html
deny from all
```

Либо вообще кладем его за пределы веб-директории.

2. Затем в коде отдаем файл через заголовки:

```html
<?php 
$filename = 'path/to/file.doc'; // путь к файлу, который будем считывать
header('Content-Type: application/msword'); // обязательно поставить нужный контент тайп
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.doc');
readfile($filename);
```