# Перенаправление пользователя из одной папки в другую

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Есть такой адрес: `userfile/file.pdf`. Надо с него перенаправить на 
`pdfreader/read.php?file=file.pdf`. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Файл `userfile/file.pdf` реально существует?

Comment: Ну не прям так могут быть и другие файлы

Comment: Мне надо чтоб не было прямого доступа через адресную строку, а через запрос) можно ли так сделать?

Comment: @bellator001, можно.

Comment: @bellator001, если вы хотите чтобы не было прямого доступа, значит файлы загружаемые пользователями надо разместить выше корня сайта (тогда точно без скрипта их не получишь).

Comment: т.е. в субдомене?

Comment: file.site.ru Вот так?

Answer (score 1):

Уже отвечал на подобный вопрос. 
[Кликаем, чтобы узнать как можно отдать файл.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445661/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E/445686#445686)
Вкратцы: закрываем директорию от доступа через .htaccess или кладем файл за пределы веб-директории. Затем отдаем файл пользователю через заголовки, как описано по ссылке выше. Код с заголовками размещаем в скрипте, к которому будет происходить обращение. И не нужны редиректы.

p.s. во избежание недопониманий: "выше корня сайта" или "за пределы веб директории" (как пишут в комментах и ответе) подразумевается вот что:
например сайт лежит локально по пути `D:\server\site.dev\www\`, 
где `\www` - веб директория. 
То есть файлы можем размещать уровнем выше например по пути `D:\server\site.dev\files\`

Comment: А если у меня сайт на хостинге, тогда какую директорию выбрать?

Comment: В большинстве случаев не принпициально. Если закрываешь директорию, кладя туда .htaccess с закрывающей директивой deny from all, то можешь и в веб директории. Или же можешь в home директорию. Часто директория к которой привязывают корень сайта выглядит как /home/public_html или же /srv/www, а ты располагаешь свою папку с файлами в /home или /srv. Но по хорошему это если там больше ничего нету, кроме твоего сайта. Я бы рекомендовал первый вариант c htaccess для понятности.

Comment: Допустим я создал эту папку так /home/username/files и положил туда .htaccess параметрами deny from all, тогда через библиотеку pdf.js как я сделаю путь до нее? Чтобы pdf.js мог читать файл находяшийся там?

Comment: По примеру pdf.js выдается совсем совершенно не скрытый файл. Его можно забрать и через pdf.js и через адресную строку. Вот страница https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html которая открывает этот файл https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf. Там ничего не прячется. 1) Для чего тебе делать редирект? 2) Если заговорил о pdf.js, то вопрос о перенаправлении задан недостаточно конкретно и в описании вопроса упоминаний о pdf.js нет. 3) Более того - файл можно через страницу с pdf.js даже загрузить! Это делает более риторическим вопрос в пункте 1.

Comment: Я переделал pdf.js. в моем случае и скачать и скопировать, и печатать запрешено. я исходник файла viewer.js измнил) Так что прямого пути там нет. И прямой путь тоже изенил в адресной строке видно только viewer.php?hesh=12123kj124hg124 типа того))

Comment: Мне нужно отключить прямой доступ к файлу, но возможность получить этот документ через pdf.js. Так можно ли?

Comment: Если ты документ получаешь по url, то у тебя все данные есть для этого. Поэкспериментируй. Задачу за тебя никто не решит.

Comment: white-imp, Спасибо вы Очень помогли)))